# Creating a method to recieve a zip file as input of a Rest Api

Tags: java, rest

I have a function like below

```
public void function(ZipEntry zipEntry){
......
}
```

I want to create a Rest Api which will accept a zip file as input and create a ZipEntry out of it and pass it to this function. I dont have any idea how to create a rest api to accept a zip file.

Please help me.

Comment: can you please be more elaborate... what is your requirement.. why do you want that the client should pass a zipped file for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method definition:

```
@Post
@Consumes("application/zip")
public void foo(InputStream is) {...}
```

In the body of your method you can use ZipInputStream to obtain each ZipEntry:

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably some code like below should work...

```
public class FileService extends Adapter
{
     @GET
     @Produces("application/xml")
     public void serviceMethod(String fileName)
     {
         ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
         //call your method here
         function(entry);
     }
}
```

hope this works for you..

Comment: this code does not useful without imports and it looks like C# code, not java.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me with Jersy .

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/zip")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response uploadZippedFile(@FormDataParam("uploadFile") InputStream file) throws IOException {

    OutputStream outpuStream = null;

    try {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Tests" + "test.zip"));
        while ((read = file.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (outpuStream != null) {
            try {
                outpuStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

Need to add dependency ,

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```